# How to toggle between CSS changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button that when pressed hides a div using 'Display: None;'.
How do I write in jquery to make the css property toggle between Display: None and Display: Block?

```
$('#help_btn').click(function(){
    $('#help_box').css('display', 'none');
});
```

when you click it again

```
$('#help_box').css('display', 'block');
```

so on and so forth. Thanks!

edit:

My css would look like this

```
#help_box {
    display: block;
}
```

and my html is

```
<div id='help_box><p> Some helpful info!</p></div>
<button id='help_btn>help?</button>
```

Comment: I recommend defining those `display` settings using a CSS class and then using jQuery's [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Can we see your relevant HTML and CSS, as well?

Comment: Why #help_box is inline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could toggle CSS classes as commented by @showdev. Or you could try this

```
$('#help_btn').click(function() {
    if($('#help_box').is(':visible')) {
        $('#help_box').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $('#help_box').css('display', 'inline');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [toggleClass();](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) as other answers suggest or use [toggle();](http://api.jquery.com/Toggle/)

```js
$('#help_btn').click(function(){
    $('#help_box').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="help_box"><p> Some helpful info!</p></div>
<button id="help_btn">help?</button>
```

Note that you have typo in your html code, you've got to properly double-quote id of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toggleClass()` to toggle two classes.

ToggleClass logic is that we add the missing class and we remove the previous one.

```js
$('#help_btn').click(function(){
    $('#help_box').toggleClass("hidden shown");
});
```

```css
.shown { display: inline; }
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <button id="help_btn">Change</button>

  <div id="help_box"><p> Some helpful info!</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create any class

`.someclass{ display: inline}`

Then toggle class

```
$('#help_btn').click(function(){
     $('#help_box').toggleClass("someClass");   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways:

The first one is by checking the css property and reversing it, something like this:

```
$(".something-i-clicked").on("click", function() {

if($(".my-class").css("display") == "none") { // if display: none; is set to .my-class

  // reverse it to display: block;
  $(".my-class").css("display", "block");

} else { // it has display: block;

  // reverse it to display: none;
  $(".my-class").css("display", "none");

}
})
```

The second way is by toggling a modifier css class, maybe like this:

```
// my_css_file.css
.my-class {
  display: none;
}
.d-block {
display: block;
}


// my_js_file.js
$(".something-i-clicked").on("click", function() {
// toggle the class
$(".my-class").toggleClass("d-block");
})
```